# What is the root of this XML document?

Tags: xml

I'm trying to integrate my app with the UPS API, however, I received an error. I think it's because I set the wrong root for my XML. I need to follow this format:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <AccessRequest xml:lang='en-US'> 
        ...
    </AccessRequest>
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <ShipmentConfirmRequest>
        ...
    </ShipmentConfirmRequest>
```

So what's the root of this XML document? I thought you were only allowed to have one.

[image: IMG]

Comment: These are **two documents** with a separate root each

Comment: But it says I have to do that under one request. So is it possible to send two XML documents in one request?

Comment: You can make a multipart mime document consisting of multiple documents. I doubt that is what UPS want though.

Comment: There is **no single root** here, and the `<?xml ..>` processing instruction shows up twice - this is **NOT** a valid XML **document**. Does the UPS API have an online doc? Care to share a link to that API documentation?

Comment: This is what is shown in the developers guide though. Let me try to add a screenshot of it in my questino

Comment: Worse "standard" response ever award to UPS?

Comment: I pasted a link to the image. Could you guys take a look? The grey makes it look like it's one document and doesn't specify a root

Comment: I think you didn't read the documentation correctly, I am looking at their Perl samples, they are using the XML::Simple to process the response, so it cannot be that there are two XMLs in one response

Comment: @nrathaus It says "UPS Shipping Services are only available for authorized UPS customers. To enforce this policy, UPS requires that every message that a client application sends include important authentication information. That information is contained in an AccessRequest XML document that must begin each message." Could you take a look at page 45 of the XML guide? I'm stumped

Comment: I am looking at the samples inside their zip file, under the perl directory.

Comment: Looks to me like you have to send two separate XML documents in sequence. The first is a "login" document, followed by the actual request(s).  Nothing special here, you just have to create two separate documents and send them one after the other.  Look for "session management" in the UPS documentation.

Comment: Documentation references to something called 'Response' as the root of the XML

Comment: Ok so they have to be two requests? I'll try it out thanks for your time @nrathaus

Comment: No its not two requests, it is one request, but it has a root element called "Response" this is according to what the Perl code shows to be using

Comment: Maybe ask here: https://developerkitcommunity.ups.com/index.php/Special:AWCforum/sc/id10 or write a "regex" that will split the response into two parts?

Comment: @nrathaus so I emailed them and the answer is that the request requires unconventional XML (seriously?. so I have to merge send two XML documents (one with AccessRequest as root, the other as ShipmentConfirmRequest) in one request.

Comment: I would take the content received and split it at the <?xml>, then feed it into your XML parser as two separate docs

Comment: @nrathaus yep exactly what I did. I start off with an empty string, then push the first part into the string, then the second part, and then make the request. It works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, this is not a well-formed XML document. It's two XML documents concatenated to each other. Apparently UPS expects you to use tools which can recognize this and break it apart.

Personally, I'd drop a note to the CTO of the company tell them their programmers need some basic XML education, including this response to illustrate why.

Meanwhile, the best workaround I see would be to  set up a filtering Stream implementation which could be wrapped around this input. Have it recognize the `<?xml version="1.0" ?>` as a signal to return end-of-file, then parse from it a second time to read the rest of the response.

Comment: hahahaaha aren't big companies supposed to have the best developers?

Comment: Not always. Sometimes the wrong manager gets the job and hires an incompetent contractor. The question is, how quickly will they say "oops" and fix it, rather than trying to defend it? Which is why I suggested going top-down rather than bottom-up.

Answer (score -1):

from the example it looks like they are providing and waiting for a not valid XML, because you are right, an XML document must have exactly one root node.

maybe you can just concatenate the 2 (or more) XML into one request, or when you get a response you split it up into valid XML documents that you can handle then.