# Ruby + Net::HTTP: How do I send two XML documents in one POST request?

Tags: ruby, xml

I have to send two XML documents in my request to the UPS API (here's my original question [What is the root of this XML document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21119164/what-is-the-root-of-this-xml-document) )

How would I do this?

```
def make_initial_request
  uri = URI.parse(UPS_API['confirm_url'])
  https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  https.use_ssl = true       

  headers = {'Content-Type' => 'text/xml'}
  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path, headers)
  request.body = xml_for_initial_request #<-- how do i split this into two documents?
  #request.body = second_xml_document #<-- i want something like that. could i just use << ?
  begin
    response = https.request(request)
  rescue
    return nil
  end
  puts "response: #{response.code} #{response.message}: #{response.body}"
  return nil if response.body.include?("Error")
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use MIME Multipart messages if the API support them ([ruby gem](https://github.com/nicksieger/multipart-post)).
Otherwise just try to concatenate files' contents `request.body =  "#{xml_for_initial_request}\n#{second_xml_document}"`